# Httplistener on Raspberry Pi

Tags: web-server, c#

I have an asynchrone Webserver in C# and it runs perfect on Windows. I get a Request every 20 ms and its answering directly.

I published my solution for linux-arm with the command:

dotnet publish -c release -r linux-arm

and copied all the files to the raspberry.

**The problem is, that the listener needs like 30 seconds to response on linux.
I dont know what causes this problem.**

Does anyone have an idea what it could be ?

My code:

```
 public void Run()
    {

        //Starts to GetContext asychrone
        var result = _listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, _listener);

        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Context ended");

    }


    public void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {

        var context = _listener.EndGetContext(result);
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";

        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        string rstr = _responderMethod(context.Request);

        byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
        response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;

        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;

        output.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        output.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Flush the stream?

Comment: The problem was, that I have a nodejs Webserver running paralell and both get called by a Driver. The nodejs WebServer made an API Call and the API was blocked what stopped the node Webserver from responding. (I changed that). The driver was waiting for a Response and didn't continue to the next webserver. I also programmed the driver asynchrone, so if one Webserver dies it doen't matter.